# How do I find information on other applications running on the computer on Mac/Cocoa/Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to find which applications are running, particularly I want to know which one has a window that has focus. So at any given time I want the app to know which application the user is actively working with. I can't figure out how to determine which app is selected, I can only see which window they are using in my app using keyedWindow. If they are not in my app it just becomes 'null'

What would be nice is if I could get the application name, and the title of the window (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [GetFrontProcess](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetFrontProcess) and [CopyProcessName](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CopyProcessName) (or [GetProcessInformation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetProcessInformation)).

Or have a look at [NSWorkspace::activeApplication](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/activeApplication).

EDIT: the reference documentation says

> It is strongly suggested that you use the [`NSRunningApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunningApplication) methods [`currentApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRunningApplication/currentApplication) or [`active`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunningApplication/isActive) to retrieve this information in post Mac OS X v10.6 targeted applications.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate this and see if it provides more info than the activeApplication from the sharedWorkspace

Comment: NSWorkspace::activeApplication is now deprecated with macOS 10.11.

Answer (score 5):

Apologies, I found what I needed. If anyone is looking to do this same thing, this snippet should help:

```
NSDictionary *activeApp = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activeApplication];
NSLog(@"Active application is: %@", (NSString *)[activeApp objectForKey:@"NSApplicationName"] );
```

Comment: can we get the name of all running applications ? @jameson

Answer (score 4):

To get a list of running applications:

```
NSArray *appNames = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

To get the active application:

```
NSRunningApplication *currentApp = [NSRunningApplication currentApplication];
```

Here's a sample project from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/AppList/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008859

These all require 10.6, according to the documentation.

Comment: Hi, how can I display the result as a string?

Comment: NSRunningApplication has a localizedName property.

Comment: how to get name of all running applications?

Comment: how to get the memory used by running application ?