# Which app has keyboard focus?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, process

In Cocoa/ Objective C I need to be able to programmatically find out which app or process has the keyboard focus. This may be done by doing a 'hit-test', but I'm not exactly sure.

I also need to get the process ID number and Window Title of app that has the keyboard focus.

Objective C or C only please!

Snippets appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973554/how-do-i-find-information-on-other-applications-running-on-the-computer-on-mac-co

Comment: It's not really clear from that question whether it's the same as this one. The frontmost application can be different from the process that has keyboard focus, by the same distinction that a single application has between its “main window” and “key window”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activeApplication](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/activeApplication) to find the front application. The [Accessibilty API](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AccessibilityAPI) can be used to look inside the application to get window titles etc.

Another option is to use the [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference) function CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo() to get a list of all windows