# How can I tell which application a CGEventRef is coming from?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

I've successfully got a demo app intercepting keyboard events. Here's the handler for them.

```
CGEventRef keyUpCallback (CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {
    NSLog(@"KeyUp event tapped!");
    return;
}
```

I want to do different things depending on which application sent the event. How can I tell which application it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application that is receiving keystrokes is presumably the active application, so you could handle the event differently depending on which application is active.  You can use the `activeapplication` method from [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSWorkspace) to get the name of the active application.

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973554/how-do-i-find-information-on-other-applications-running-on-the-computer-on-mac-co) about getting the active application.

Comment: Moreover, an application didn't send the event; a keyboard (of some kind) sent the event. An application *receives* the event. It is possible that an application did make up an event and post it to the queue, but in that case, it intends for you to handle it no differently from a real event with the same attributes as the one it forged. Either way, it's not possible to tell what application, if any, created and posted the event.

Comment: There's a complication: there's such a thing as a non-activating panel (see [`NSNonactivatingPanelMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000244-SW10)). So, the app with "key" status (focus) may not be active. I don't know of a way to find out which app actually has focus in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Here how it goes:

```
int64_t processIdTarget = CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGEventTargetUnixProcessID);
int64_t processIdSource = CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGEventSourceUnixProcessID);
```

`processIdSource` shows you application sender and `processIdTarget` stands for receiver.

For example you can open virtual keyboard and send events with it. As virtual keyboard is process in user space you will get it's pid as `processIdSource`. But for most of cases you will get `0` as `processIdSource`.

After you got application's pid you can create `NSRunningApplication` instance and get bunch of information from it.

Answer (score 0):

This shows process ID of the application that sent the event:

```
NSLog(@"Target PID:%lld",CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGEventTargetUnixProcessID));
```