# Unable to find running application in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, process, nsworkspace

I am getting the list of running applications in Cocoa with the following code:

```
for (NSRunningApplication *app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
   MNSLog(@"%@",[app localizedName]);
}
```

However an application I started from a terminal session is not appearing in the list ('Terminal' is well appearing). The application was started from the same user which is executing the cocoa code.

Is my launched application under Terminal ? And in such a case how can I find its name and arguments ?

Running ps in another terminal session show my process properly.

Comment: Does your app use the window server?

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973554/how-do-i-find-information-on-other-applications-running-on-the-computer-on-mac-c

Comment: Processes you start from Terminal that don't have UIs or otherwise contact the window server are not "applications", for future reference — they are just processes. Apple documentation also sometimes uses the word "tool". I think some people are getting confused because of this. When you're dealing with things at this level, generally Cocoa isn't going to help you; you need to use the lower-level BSD (or even Mach, though only as a last resort) APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `NSTask` to execute the `ps` Shell command. You can check the `ps` man page to determine which arguments you want to pass it based on the information you want to get back. Use `NSPipe` and `NSFileHandle` to get the results from the task.

If you want to do some filtering you can pipe the `ps` output through `grep` before your app picks up the result.

For your first question, I think `NSWorkspace` can only see apps that use the window server so you will only see Terminal, not the executables that it is running internally.

Comment: Did you refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973554/how-do-i-find-information-on-other-applications-running-on-the-computer-on-mac-c??

Comment: Good point as I have no window. Will try the ps approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sysctl` or `ps` command to get a list of all BSD processes. Have look at [unable to detect application running with another user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821357/944634)