# How to obtain the foreground window name of the current application in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'd like to obtain the foreground window name of the current application in Objective-C.

Though I found several methods to obtain the current application name, I cannot find ones to obtain the foreground windows.

- [What is the 'correct' way to identify the currently active application in OSX 10.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348627/what-is-the-correct-way-to-identify-the-currently-active-application-in-osx-10) (for MacOSX >= 10.6)
- [How do I find information on other applications running on the computer on Mac/Cocoa/Obj-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973554/how-do-i-find-information-on-other-applications-running-on-the-computer-on-mac-c) (for MacOSX < 10.6)

For instance, if there is an application,

```
 Text Editor
    [*] foo.txt
    [ ] bar.txt
```

which `*` indicates the current window,
then I'd like to make a function `getCurrentWindow()` to return "`foo.txt`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo function.

> Return Value:
>   An array of CFDictionaryRef types, each of which contains information about one of the windows in the current user session.

Key kCGWindowName in these dictionaries is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I have succeed to obtain the desired information by using the function.